# How to "document.write();" on the same page?

Tags: document

Basically, I have made a form which allows you to input 2 numbers, and when you press the 'Add' button, the program writes the answer onto the screen, the only thing is when the answer is written, it appears on a separate page. How do I get it to write to the same page, below is the HTML code:

```
<form type="twoNum" method="get">
<input type="float" placeholder="Enter first number here..." name="num1" id="n1"/>
&nbsp;
<input type="float" placeholder="Enter second number here..." name="num2" id="n2"/>
<input type="button" value="Add" name="sndfunct" onClick="twoNum(this.form);"/>
</form>
```

Below is the Javascript code:

```
function twoNum(form)
{
var num1 = form.num1.value;
var num2 = form.num2.value;
var intNum1 = parseFloat(num1);
var intNum2 = parseFloat(num2);
document.writeln(intNum1 + intNum2);
}
```

Comment: Look up the DOM API; although `document.write` is fine for simple, inline things, you need to learn that to do a lot of useful things with a document. (Like this.) It also looks nicer than `on*` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that using `document.write()` is considered bad practice. E.g. see [the warning](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/dom.html#dom-document-write) on the W3C web site.

Furthermore, you can’t use it to edit a closed document. `document.write()` can only be used while the document is being loaded.

In order to do what you want, you should have a `<span id="foo"></span>` somewhere in your document, and then do:

```
document.getElementById("foo").textContent = intNum1 + intNum2;
```

This will insert your number *inside* your span element. Actually, it replaces the content of the (previously empty) span element.

Edit: Of course, it can be any kind of element. I used a span element just for the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `<p id="answer"></p>` in the form. Then create `var answer=intNum1 + intNum2` and after that instead `document.writeln(intNum1 + intNum2)` write `document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=answer`!